# Write simultaneousely to two streams

Tags: c, linux, io, stream

Is there a way to to couple two streams (or file descriptors) together so that writing to one stream will also write to the second one? (C, Linux)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User laalto is correct, but on Linux, the function you are looking for is called `fopencookie`.  Correcting laalto's example for Linux results in:

```
int my_writefn(void *cookie, const char *data, int n) {
  FILE **files = (FILE **)cookie;
  fwrite(data, n, 1, files[0]);
  return fwrite(data, n, 1, files[1]);
}

int noop(void) { return 0; }
cookie_io_functions_t my_fns = {
  (void*) noop,
  (void*) my_writefn,
  (void*) noop,
  (void*) noop
};

FILE *files[2] = ...;

FILE *f = fopencookie((void *)files, "w", my_fns);

// ... use f as you like ...
```

When you write to `f`, the system will execute your `my_writefn` function passing it the data that was passed to `fwrite`.  To make things easier, you may also want to change the buffering for your file stream to be line oriented:

```
setvbuf(f, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

That will buffer up the data passed to `fwrite` until a newline is output or any data is read from any stream attached to the processes (e.g. stdin).  **NOTE:** you must call `sevbuf` after `fopencookie` but before any data is written to the stream.

I use line buffering because I usually use `fopencookie` to redirect stderr to syslog, or over a network socket, and processing line oriented data is easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

Use `funopen` or `fwopen` and supply your own write function that writes to multiple `FILE*`s.

Example:

```
FILE *files[2] = ...;

FILE *f = fwopen((void *)files, my_writefn);

// ... use f as you like ...

int my_writefn(void *cookie, const char *data, int n) {
  FILE **files = (FILE **)cookie;
  fwrite(data, n, 1, files[0]);
  return fwrite(data, n, 1, files[1]);
}
```

(Error handling omitted.)

Note that `funopen` and `fwopen` are BSD and not in standard Linux. I'm not aware if there's a Linux-compatible equivalent.

Comment: Apparently, no. They are not in man pages (at least on my system).

Comment: funopen is on BSD and Mac OS X.  On Linux use fopencookie.

Comment: @mark4o: Thanks for the info. @Jack: Seems like the implementation using fopencookie() would be quite similar. Not updating my answer here but you should have some pointers to go forward with.

Comment: This saves computer time.  I'm not sure it saves programmer time.  Neat trick, though (even if not completely portable, where portable = "among unices").

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that came to mind to me was also "tee".  So, let's combine C and the shell with popen:

```
FILE * multi_out;

multi_out = popen( "tee file1.out > file2.out", "w");
/* error checks, actual work here */
pclose( multi_out);
/* error checks here */
```

As a Unix bigot, I have assumed you are not trying this on Windows.

Comment: This way we can write to more than two files also. Just the matter of tricky use of tee. ref. http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/05/how-to-use-tee-command.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's what you want, but 'tee' in unix does something similar.

Comment: So the "C++" guy gets modded up, but you get modded down for suggesting to "build on the work of others".  That's not right...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something similar to functionality of `tee` with [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).

Comment: Do you have an example for C? Because that is strictly C++ ;)