# Can I create a memory-mapped FILE * in C/Objective-C on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I have a library which consumes a `FILE *` and outputs data to another `FILE *`.

I want to handle both the input to this library and the output from this library in memory without reading/writing to/from a file on the disk.

We're doing this in iOS - so running the library as a separate app and using `stdin`/`stdout` isn't (as far as I know) a viable option.

Comment: there's [fmemopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) and [open_memstream](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html), but I don't know if they are available on iOS

Comment: No, they aren't available on iOS or OS X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because ObjC is a superset of C, all you have to do is `#import/#include <stdio.h>` to gain access to the `funopen()` which in itself contains the functions `readfn`, `writefn`, `seekfn`, and `closefn`. And fwopen which has an example showing how to write to two streams at this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043871/945847).

<strike>Mac OSX and iOS don't include `fmemopen` and `open_memstream`because they are apparently [unportable linux functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20160927172523/http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2008/Feb/msg00059.html)</strike>

As of macos 10.13, ios 11.0, tvos 11.0, and watchos 4.0, `fmemopen` and `open_memstream` along with a few other helpful POSIX.1-2008 standard functions are available in stdio.

Comment: @KurtRevis, I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: OK then, how exactly do you use fopen() to get a FILE* from a block of memory, not a file?

Comment: @KurtRevis fwopen and funopen would work as well for writing, especially to two files as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1043871/945847)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm providing such funky answers, I haven't touched IO C functions in a while.

Comment: *highly unportable* is a bit strong - the functions are available in the GNU, uClibc and Newlib libc implementations and part of POSIX since 2008

Comment: @Christoph to quote the mailing list answerer >Leopard
conforms to UNIX03, not POSIX.1-2008.

Comment: @CodaFi: it did't feel right to me to call something which is available in Linux, Haiku, Cygwin, AmigaOS highly unportable just because it's missing from OSX

Comment: The OS X people seem to have a stick up their ass wrt to standards compliance. That they don't conform to POSIX.1 2008 yet doesn't mean that they should not attempt to implement the very simply `fmemopen()` function anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://github.com/shyuep/pyhull/tree/master/src/fmemopen, I've tested it myself on a Mac OSX 10.8.2 and it is working ok.

Author states it should also work on iOS.

Comment: I've tried compiling the above library on my mac and i get an error `error: no matching function for call to 'funopen'` are there any special flags needed?

Comment: i'm on `Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)` if that helps